# Does middleman s3_sync ignore .txt files by default?

Tags: middleman

It looks like middleman s3_sync doesn't upload my robots.txt. Is there a way to enable it to always upload a specific file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the version of Middleman S3_Sync that you are using.

Versions 3.0.x build the list of files based on the content of the build directory. In that case, copying the file into the build directory will include it in the sync.

Versions 3.3.x moved to the Middleman sitemap in preparation of MM 4. It currently only syncs the files that Middleman is aware of. Copying a file into the build directory doesn't make S3_Sync aware of it.

In the second case, there are two options available.

The first one is to move robot.txt to the source directory. This will include it in the sitemap and it will be sync'ed.

The second is to open an issue (or even better, a pull request) that will ask for the ability to include files that originate from outside of the source directory.

It would help to get the version of Middleman and s3_sync that you are using.

Comment: Perfect answer. This is not a issue , more of a feature request then. My file gets added by a ruby gem and put inside build at the LAST step in my build, making Middleman unaware of it.

Comment: I had just noticed the comment notification. I have created [issue 108](https://github.com/fredjean/middleman-s3_sync/issues/108) to track this.